# Shouldn't 2 subsequent 'If statements' be the equivalent of the logical 'and' operator?

Tags: java, if-statement

How come these two outputs differ if 2 subsequent 'if' statements is the equivalent of saying "If statement 1 is true and statement 2 is true, return 'i'..

```java
public int majorityElement(int[] nums) {
  if (nums.length == 1)
    return nums[0];
        
  HashMap<Integer, Integer> elements = new HashMap<>();
  for(int i : nums) {
    if(elements.containsKey(i) && (elements.get(i) +1 > nums.length / 2)) {
      return i;
    } else {
      elements.put(i, elements.getOrDefault(i,0) + 1);
    }
  }
  return -999;
}

/*
  Input
  nums = [2,2,1,1,1,2,2]

  Output: 2
  Expected: 2
*/
```

Compared to this snippet:

```java
public int majorityElement(int[] nums) {
  if (nums.length == 1)
    return nums[0];
        
  HashMap<Integer, Integer> elements = new HashMap<>();
  for (int i : nums) {
    if(elements.containsKey(i)){
      if(elements.get(i) +1 > nums.length / 2){
        return i;
      }
    } else {
      elements.put(i, elements.getOrDefault(i,0) + 1);
    }
  }
  return -999;
}

/*
  Input
  nums = [2,2,1,1,1,2,2]

  Output: -999
  Expected: 2
*/
```

Comment: They would be equivalent on their own, but the `else` only corresponds to the outer `if`. If you nest part of the condition, the `else` doesn't apply to that.

Comment: Your first example has only two possible states: `if (a && b) { c } else { d }` but your second example has three: `if (a) { if (b) { c } ...x?... } else { d }`. If `a`, but not `b`, nothing happens: you don't return, _and_ you don't hit the `else` case.

Answer (score 3):

Well, time to find a phone, you have a call to make.

The difference isn't in the `if`. Indeed, this:

```
if (a) {
  if (b) { foo(); }
}
```

is semantically identical to:

```
if (a && b) { foo(); }
```

even including the shortcircuiting behaviour (in both of those, if `a` resolves to `false`, expression `b` is not calculated at all. So if `b` has sideeffects, say its `someMethod()` where the method changes things or prints things, or it's a side-effect-having expression like `c++ > 5` (which as a side effect, increments c), that method doesn't run, and c doesn't get incremented.

What's different is the `else`, though. Your first snippet does:

```
if (a) {
  if (b) { foo(); }
} else {
  bar();
}
```

and your second is:

```
if (a && b) foo();
else bar();
```

foo() is invoked only if both `a` and `b`. However, `bar()` in the first snippet is invoked if not a. Whereas in the second case it's invoked if not a **or** not b.

In your first snippet, it boils down to:

|  | a=true | a=false |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **b=true** | `foo()` | `bar()` |
| **b=false** | *nothing happens* | `bar()` |

your second one is subtly different:

|  | a=true | a=false |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **b=true** | `foo()` | `bar()` |
| **b=false** | **`bar()`** | `bar()` |

Comment: Wonderful take. Can you switch these two around as I have edited the post, for newbies to come. Thank you for your expertise.

Answer (score 0):

It's AND in the sense that the code inside the block only execute if both conditions are true

```java
if(elements.containsKey(i) && (elements.get(i) +1 > nums.length / 2)){
    return i;
}

same as

if(elements.containsKey(i)){
    if(elements.get(i) +1 > nums.length / 2){
        return i;
    }
}
```

But you also have an else statement, and the behavior is different for that part since the else is for the outer condition only:

```java
if(!(elements.containsKey(i) && (elements.get(i) +1 > nums.length / 2))){
    elements.put(i, elements.getOrDefault(i,0) + 1);
}

is not the same as

if(!(elements.containsKey(i)){
    elements.put(i, elements.getOrDefault(i,0) + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two techniques you provide are not at all equivalent. In the first example, it is possible that the following might happen:

```
elements.containsKey(i)  <-- true

elements.get(i) +1 > nums.length / 2  <-- false
```

In this case, neither the

```
return i
```

nor the

```
elements.put(i, elements.getOrDefault(i,0) + 1);
```

Will be executed and your code will produce unexpected results. Hence your question here.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example has only two possible states:

```
if (a && b) {
  state 1 // your code returns, so you don't even need "else" in this case
} else {
  state 2 // your code updates the list
}
```

but your second example has three:

```
if (a) {
  if (b) {
    state 1 // the return call
  }
  state 3 // you do not have code here, so it "kicks in" but does nothing
} else {
  state 2 // the update call
}
```

So in a situation where `a` is true, but `b` is not, you hit state 3 instead of state 2, and because you have no code there, nothing happens:

- we don't return so we stay in the function, *and*
- we don't hit the `else` because `a` was true, so:

Nothing gets updated.

At every iteration of the loop we end up "doing nothing", the loop finishes, and we hit the end of the function where you return -999.